# gmaps4rails v2 - map type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

How do you set the map type to HYBRID or SATELLITE ? I thought it would be some option to pass to the provider hash, but if it's the case I can't find the proper one.

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 0,
      "lng": 0,
      "picture": {
        "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
        "width":  36,
        "height": 36
      },
      "infowindow": "hello!"
    }
  ]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass whatever map options you need from google as an object on the `provider` key.

Its documented with the source [here.](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/google/builders/map.coffee#L6)

In your case:

```
var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID };
handler.buildMap({ provider: mapOptions, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  ...
```